# How to retrieve Test case log from Soap UI

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, groovy, soapui

Iam trying to retrieve each step Response time from TestCase Log when we Execute Particular Test case or TestSuite. Can any one please suggest how to that using Groovy script.

Comment: Hi can any one please tell me how to solve this issue??

Comment: Did you read the page I posted?

Comment: downvote and response below ... it doesn't take that long to find suitable information

Answer (score 0):

from smartBear community information ([here](https://community.smartbear.com/))

you can do :

```
log.info "Time taken" + testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Request 1"].testRequest.response.timeTaken
```

That should do ... but the best way to find is to search a little, you'll benefit from it

Comment: how to retrieve time taken from TestCase Log when we Execute Particular Test case withourt using Request 1.                                      
Ex:- Am sending request in step1 through excel using GET method and getting response in the same step1. so am not using Request1 to send or receive response. I need to retrieve tescse time taken from Testcase log

Comment: sorry, it's not clear ... what do you execute, a request ? a groovy script ? could you add more explanation in your topic (do edit it), please ?